# How to configure .dll file in Java?

Tags: java, dll, classpath, jacob

I am using [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/develop) jar file in my java application.

This Jacob jar file comes with a .dll file. I have added Jacob jar file to my classpath. But when I execute my application a runtime error occurs as

```
"couldn't load jacob-1.15-M3-x86.dll file"
```

How can I load this .dll file?

Edited:=================================================================================

I had set the "path" environment varaible to the dir that contains my .dll file and loading that .dll file as follows

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jacob-1.15-M3-x86.dll");
}
```

but the following error occured

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jacob-1.15-M3-x86.dll in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at TemplateClass.TemplateClass.<clinit>(TemplateClass.java:14)
```

Comment: placing the dlls in system32 folder of windows solved the issue for me

Answer (score 10):

The 'jacob-1.15-M3-x86.dll' needs to be in a place where your the operating system can find it. You have a few options here:

- You can place the .dll file in the directory you started your application from. If you have a batch script to start your application, it would be that directory. If you are starting in some sort of application server, it would typically be the 'bin' directory.
- You can place the .dll file somewhere in the %PATH% environment variable. I may be easier to just update your PATH environment variable to include the directory that contains your .dll file.
- Another option is to place your .dll into the %SystemRoot%\system32 directory. Usually this is 'C:\Windows\system32'. This option is not usually recommended unless it is a shared library like the MSCVRT runtime.

One other possible issue you might have. If the .dll is compiled as 32-bit, then you must be running in the 32-bit Java runtime. Likewise, if it is a 64-bit .dll it needs to be run in a 64-bit JRE.

Comment: My problem is solved. Thanks for that.

{...You can place the .dll file in the directory you started your application from} Do you mean that the dir where the main class resides? If yes, then why the file should be in the dir where my batch script resides if I use batch script?

Could you please explain your first point with more focus on the point when I want to start in an application server?

Comment: It should be in the directory where you start the Java process from, not your main class directory.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, that's not a compilation error but a runtime error.

My guess would be that your DLL needs to be on the `PATH`. Not `CLASSPATH`, but `PATH`, because that's where Windows looks for DLLs. Try either extending your PATH to include the location of your DLL, or do what many other people do: Dump the DLL into `\Winnt\System\System32` or whatever the system directory is called on your box. Wherever all the other DLLs are, in other words.

**Update**

The error message you post, thankfully, is pointing out the exact problem. You can solve it by putting the directory containing your DLL into `java.library.path` This Sun forum thread shows a nice example: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=627890

Actually, that's a lot less clean than it should be; this seems to be one of the "shadier" areas in Java. The thread wanders around a lot, I do advise you to read all the way through to see some problems and solutions. I think you'll be able to succeed with a little trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

Other options :

- set the property java.library.path to the directory containing the dll. Example : 
  java -Djava.library.path="path/to/directory/containing/the/dll" -jar appli.jar
- in the code, load the dll explicitly, with System.load.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  [This](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html) will give you all the right steps to follow.

Comment: If he's running on Linux, JACOB will not be very useful!

Comment: I'm assuming that there's an .so for Linux.  Same comments apply.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `System.loadLibrary()` **don't include the `.dll` at the end**.

Also, if you are not setting `java.library.path` to point to the folder containing the DLL then the DLL should be in the directory where you launch your Java application from.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I see that the question is not "answered", so maybe none of the options above worked.

One of my last hypothesis was that the Jacob.dll is missing its dependency.

What I did was to get [depend](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and check if all the dependence, used by Jacob are loaded.
Of course this works for Windows.

Cheers!