# Forcing application to use a dll in a specific folder

Tags: java

I am responding to a pervious post :

[How to force a VB6 program to use a dll in a specified folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505784/how-to-force-a-vb6-program-to-use-a-dll-in-a-specified-folder)

(Although the application I have is not an application written in VBA - but Java)

I have added an empty txt file in the same folder as my .exe application.

IpmGun.exe.local

In the same folder is also the mqic32.dll which the application is using. Unfortunately it does not work. When if run IpmGun.exe I get "Server DLL (MQIC32.dll) not loaded"

Any ideas how to bridge this problem?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused -- how are you trying to use a dll with Java? Are you using JNI? JNA?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082026/how-to-configure-dll-file-in-java which seems to address the same problem.

Comment: What if you provide the full path to your dll, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IpmGun is not a Java programm but a Windows 32 bits executable. The mqic32.dll you want to load is part of the IBM websphere message broker. When you install the MQ Local Client software on your machine (freely availlable from IBM) the dll will get loaded. If you can not install it on the machine of your choice, maybe you can first install it somewhere else and afterwards copy all dll's to the folder where Ipmgun is currently located.