# UnsatisfiedLinkError Exception

Tags: java

I get the following error in my web applet:

**no jacob-1.17-x86.dll in java.library.path**

I added the DLL in to:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin

and in to the CLASSPATH

BUT no luck:(

Here is my java.library.path output:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin; 
>   C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;
>   C:\Windows\system32; C:\Windows;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin; C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
>   C:\Windows\System32\Wbem; C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
>   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\; c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
>   Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\

Also, my OS is 64, no idea why it is pointing to x86..

Comment: This should help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082026/how-to-configure-dll-file-in-java

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941234/unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-jacob-and-jre-1-7?rq=1

Comment: The first one fixed it. Strangely enough, the question itself what helped me fix it, not the way I would have liked it to be fixed, I didn't want to load the library from the code, but it works so thanks!